# which path for WindowBuilder Pro Eclipse is correct?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

When I was trying to install WindowBuilder plugin I found 2 sources:
http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/release/R201109201200/3.7/
and 
http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7
How I understood those are different version and don't know which select. Can you help me, which version is better for developing a swing apps?

**UPDATE**

The first link has version 1.1.0 and the second has 1.3.0.

Comment: The second one is more official as stated in http://code.google.com/javadevtools/download-wbpro.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is the correct one. Google has donated Window Builder Pro to the Eclipse foundation, and all new development and releases come from Eclipse. The update site at Google contains an older version of Window Builder.
The project homepage for WB is [www.eclipse.org/wb](http://www.eclipse.org/wb)

Comment: It looks like the WB Eclipse project comes from the same guys from Google. http://www.eclipse.org/proposals/tools.windowbuilder/ See QA #3 and #4 in http://code.google.com/javadevtools/eclipse-donation-faq.html. So both links are valid for Eclipse 3.7

Comment: Even when both sites are identical, i would use the one from Eclipse. Main development is now on Eclipse side.

Comment: Yes, I agree. The only difference is now both links either from Eclipse.org and code.google.com are valid :)